# When and how clean Magento cache on front server?

Tags: cache, server-setup, crontab

My Magento store front server have no routine to clear cache, what result in slow Magento(cause it take to long to read cache files).
Front server do not run cron.php, all jobs run over backend server.

Today, i am cleaning Magento front server `var/cache` folder manually to speed up Magento and don`t let cache files grow too much.

How can i automate this routine? Create a cron to **rm -rf * from var/cache** one time a day? There is a custom module to help with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The best and only way is to use the magento cron job. Do not rm manually these files, let this done by the cronjob.
Take a look into the shell directory in your magento installation directory. 
There is a file called **log.php**

Try on your console:

```
php -f log.php clean
```

Magento never deletes all entrys in your cachefolder and your database. This is because Magento needs some **"old"** data.

Comment: Perfect. Do you know when should a run? Every hour, every day?

Comment: According to my research, this command just clear Magento log, not the cache. I just found this article, https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-flush-your-magento-cache.html, but it not tells me when clear, but the command ```php -r 'require "app/Mage.php"; Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();'``` works